atlas.microsoft API is not returning results within the specified bbox
I am using the atlas.microsoft.com/geocode API to perform some searches. My request URL is:
https://atlas.microsoft.com/geocode?bbox=5.716753,36.478991,20.152788,46.199075&subscription-key=xxxxxxxx&api-version=2023-06-01&coordinates=11.199319,43.804378&top=15&query=Bol

However, I am getting results that are outside the specified bbox area, and I can't understand why. According to the documentation, the bbox should be formatted as lon1,lat1,lon2,lat2, which seems correct to me.
Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong?
